# Language level is invalid or missing in pom.xml. Current project JDK is 11. Specify language level in project

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-11

I am generate the following project and its dependencies with Spring Boot 3 from Spring initializr

[image: Spring initializr]

Opening and running project in Intellij IDEA the following output is returned

```
error: release version 17 not supported

Language level is invalid or missing in pom.xml. Current project JDK is 11. Specify language level in webflux-project
```

I have jdk 11 installed on my system

```
> java --version
java 11.0.14 2022-01-18 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.14+8-LTS-263)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.14+8-LTS-263, mixed mode)
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.gamesmall</groupId>
    <artifactId>webflux</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>webflux</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot with WebFlux</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

how to resolved this issue ?

Comment: Why is `<java.version>17</java.version>` if you're targeting JDK 11?

Comment: Do you want the project to use Java 11 or Java 17?

Comment: @Michael automatically Sprint initializr puts it

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0) Spring Boot 3.0 will require Java 17 (jdk 17). So during project generation change Spring Boot version from 3.* to 2.7.* and solved !